# Vspackage development, how to get code elements in a file or in a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vspackage, vs-extensibility

I can add code to a file by using codeModel.

Now I want to add code elements like variables to a specified class.

So the first thing I need to do is to get the class I want to modify.
Following is my code:

```
IVsProject project = YHMExtensionHelper.GetSelectedProject();
int found;
uint itemId;
VSDOCUMENTPRIORITY[] pdwPriority = new VSDOCUMENTPRIORITY[1];
project.IsDocumentInProject("TEST.h", out found, pdwPriority, out itemId);
if (found == 0 || itemId == 0)
    return;
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider oleSp = null;
project.GetItemContext(itemId, out oleSp);
if (oleSp == null)
   return;
ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider(oleSp);
EnvDTE.ProjectItem item = sp.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.ProjectItem)) as EnvDTE.ProjectItem;
var codeModel = item.FileCodeModel;
var eles = codeModel.CodeElements;
for (int i = 0; i < eles.Count; i++)
{
    var singleItem = eles.Item(i);
    var str = singleItem.Name;
}
```

But this doesn't work, I can get the eles.Count, I can't get any item by eles.Item(i).

In TEST.h there are a simple c++ class.

Please tell my how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, I can use to enum all code element in a element.

```
foreach (CodeElement element in eles)
{
   if(element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)
   {
      CodeClass cl = element as CodeClass;
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```